# PostgreSQL: PreparedStatement to execute set schema command

Tags: postgresql, java, prepared-statement

I need to execute in a Java application a `SET schema ?` statement, where the placeholder is replaced by a value provided at runtime by the caller.

I assumed I could use `PreparedStatement` to overcome potential SQL injection, but if I try to execute a prepared statement I get a `PSQLException` with message

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"  Position: 18
```

If I do execute the SQL by just concatenating the schema name by doing:

```
public void executeSetSchema(Connection con, String schema){
  try{
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     stmt.execute("SET SCHEMA '" + schema + "'");

  } catch(Exception){}
}
```

Then everything works as expected.

Clearly, this happens with all the latest releases of PostgreSQL

Why I cannot use a PreparedStatement and what should I do instead to prevent SQL injection here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass identifiers as parameters. It's similar to `select * from ?`

However, you can use a [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) to set the search path:

```
public void executeSetSchema(Connection con, String schema) {
  try (
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select set_config('search_path', ?, false)");
  ) {
     pstmt.setString(1, schema);
     stmt.execute();
  } catch(Exception) {
  }
}
```

I moved the `prepareStatement()` call into a try-with-resources so that the statement is closed properly.

Comment: Yeah, mine example was to make it easy-to-read. I do use Apache `DBUtils.closeQuietly` for every statement and connection.

Lemme try your solution, but now I do see the problem, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have working code with

```
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     stmt.execute("set search_path to '" + schema + "'");
```